# Safe method of JS page redirect using a <select> element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, content-security-policy

How to redirect a page using JS, based on the value of a `<select>` element

I want to replace a load of `onchange=""` inline JS actions attached to HTML elements. For example, I have a `<select>` that fires an inline `onchange=""` event that takes the selected option and redirects using `window.document.location.href='`'. I want something that passes CSP rules (no inline scripting) and uses `.addEventListener`. This is what I came up with. It works, but looks clunky. Is there a better way ?

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",EventListeners);

function EventListeners() {
  document.getElementById("MySelect").addEventListener("change", ChangeSomething);
}
function ChangeSomething() {
 var sel = document.getElementById("MySelect");
 var sel_opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].id;
 window.document.location.href='page.php?id=' + sel_opt;
}
```

For some reason, if I try :
`document.getElementById("MySelect").addEventListener("change", ChangeSomething);`
as the first line, I get an error, saying getElementById(...) is null.

Comment: Put the ID in the value of the option, not the ID, so you can just use `sel.value`

Comment: You can just use `this` in the event listener instead of selecting the element by ID.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element for why you get that error.

Comment: Why do you feel this is clunky?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar but would using just the option ID work ? I need to get the option that is selected, as the form isn't being POSTed, I'm just listening for a JS event. How would I use ```this``` if I'm not passing a reference to the ```<select>``` ?
My comment about clunkiness is because I have to write a separate ```EventListeners()``` function.

Comment: The ID works, but that means different menus can't have the same value, because IDs are supposed to be unique. Also, the syntax for getting the option ID is more complicated: `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].id` instead of just `sel.value`.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks.